# how can i store more than just one letter in a variable?

Tags: c++, string, char

with char i get this error:
.\main.cpp(6) : error C2015: too many characters in constant

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that was generating the error, along with the error.  Then we don't have to use our psychic powers, and our psychic powers are a finite resource.

Answer (score 6):

A `char` only holds one character:

```
char bar = 'a';
```

If you want more, use a string constant to initialize a character array:

```
char foo[] = "This is my thing";
```

Answer (score 6):

Given the file extension `cpp`, I am going to go out on a limb and assume you are using C++. If so, use the [`string`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_%28C%2B%2B%29) class to store a string.

Answer (score 2):

See [Compiler Error C2015](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7f33t4h%28VS.80%29.aspx) for an explanation of the error. MSDN is a great source of knowledge and usually describes the error messages from Visual Studio (as I assume you are using) in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use a string i.e. array of characters For example `char s[] = "Hello";`

Comment: Or, if you're not planning on modifying the string, a `char *s = "Hello";` will do.

Comment: That uses a deprecated conversion in C++ though, use `const char* s = "Hello";` or preferably `std::string`.

Comment: In fact, in C++0x the conversion is not allowed anymore.